# What kind of timer is most suitable for MIDI timing?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, midi

I am writing a simple MIDI app for my own use, in C# and .NET 4.x.

I assume that commercial DAWs (on the Windows platform that is) use [Windows Multimedia Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-timer-reference) for timing the playback of MIDI data. But I can't verify this, since commercial stuff is closed-source.

I'm hoping someone has knowledge in this area, and can tell me if my assumption is right. Or, are these DAWs using timers I'm not aware of? I want to make sure there isn't anything more suitable that I've overlooked.

Comment: Audio, in general, requires accurate timing. Choosing a platform with unpredictable performance characteristics, like .NET, is questionable.

Comment: @IInspectable Good point and I'm aware of it - I may port what I've done so far to C++/Native WinApi if early tests demonstrate issues. But the question around what timer to use still stands in either case.

Comment: It is my understanding that MIDI requires millisecond accuracy. I doubt that any commercial DAW delegates that sort of accuracy to standard system timers.

Comment: You don't need a driver to spin in a loop until a high precision timer (like `rdtsc`) reaches its target time. If I were to implement a DAW on Windows without dedicated MIDI hardware I'd probably use a system timer to land at a time point prior to the target time, and then actively spin for higher accuracy.

Comment: @IInspectable Indeed, that's my suspicion too, but DAWs like Reaper don't appear to install any special system-level drivers that I thought would be necessary for precision timing. So the mystery remains - if not existing system timers, what timers are DAWs using for MIDI playback (not to be confused with digital audio or video, which is quite different)

Comment: As I pointed out, you don't need a timer to implement accurate timing. Requesting the current (high precision) time in a loop is sufficiently accurate for nanosecond timings. Also, you often don't need to install a driver to communicate with a device. The system already has drivers for standard protocols like USB that clients can use to control custom hardware without the need to install a kernel driver.

Comment: @IInspectable But, using a timer is key in achieving low CPU usage. Even intelligent "targeted" spinning would drive a CPU core to 100% during periods of dense MIDI. Looking at Reaper and Cakewalk CPU usage, I see no evidence of spinning - very low CPU usage even in dense MIDI tracks.

Comment: If you want to know how existing DAW systems are implemented, you're going to have to reverse engineer their respective implementations, assuming this is legal in your jurisdiction. As a preliminary step you can inspect their import tables and see if/whether they import system-provided timer interfaces. Though I doubt you'd be able to see a timer/active spinning hybrid implementation sketched out in a previous comment by looking at the CPU consumption in Task Manager.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm sorry - I think we both got off track here. I'm hoping that someone with experience in coding DAWs or MIDI apps actually knows the answer to my question and will share it with us. So I will give it some time and see if we get an answer, fingers crossed :-)

Comment: Windows doesn't provide any timers with millisecond accuracy. A software system that requires millisecond accuracy isn't going to be using any of Windows' timers. That is essentially the answer to your question.

Comment: Yes, timeBeginPeriod() and timeSetEvent() gives you a timer accurate to 1 millisecond.  Plenty good enough for human ears.

Comment: @han `timeBeginPeriod` isn't guaranteed to allow for a resolution down to 1ms. And resolution is not the same thing as accuracy. Besides, 1ms is **far** from the timing requirements of MIDI 2.0. This is used in professional music production. Being good enough for human ears doesn't quite cut it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I have not had the privilege of coding for commercial DAW projects specifically, I do have experience in coding for scenarios where the accurate timing of events is important, including MIDI processing/routing.

Your assumption is correct. Well-coded MIDI sequencers use the Windows Multimedia Timer to schedule the sending of MIDI messages to MIDI devices.

Microsoft's [Multimedia Timer Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-timers) actually [mentions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/about-multimedia-timers) MIDI sequencing as an example use:

> These timer services are useful for applications that demand high-resolution timing. For example, a MIDI sequencer requires a high-resolution timer because it must maintain the pace of MIDI events within a resolution of 1 millisecond.

How to use the timer is for another topic, I won't get into that here. But I'd like to point out a few things:

- All modern hardware supports a timer resolution of 1 millisecond, it's basically a given, but you should still call `timeGetDevCaps` to make sure before calling `timeBeginPeriod`.
- Using the multimedia timer, at 1 millisecond resolution, will have the effect of quantizing your MIDI messages to a 1 millisecond grid +/- some variance/jitter. In the vast majority of cases this is a non-issue because that is still a sufficiently fine resolution to provide reasonably nuanced timing, so far as musical timing goes anyway. If you absolutely need sub-millisecond timing, you will have to do as @iinspectable suggests - use the timer to get "close" and then spin to precisely time the sending of your MIDI messages. However, this approach comes at a cost. I don't know what your intentions are for the app, but should you have several simultaneous MIDI tracks playing, each with continuous controllers and pitch bend, you'll find your app spinning all the time and you'll peg a CPU core to 100% which is just plain bad.
- Do look into Windows' [Multimedia Class Scheduler Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multimedia-class-scheduler-service) to get prioritized access to CPU resources for your MIDI playback thread.
- Don't be discouraged by comments from @iinspectable. You can absolutely do high-performance MIDI sequencing using C#/.NET. Your only concern needs to be that of the garbage collector unpredicatably pausing your app. You can always code in a way that minimizes GC (e.g. use structs not classes, don't create/destroy anything during playback). Also consider using [GC.TryStartNoGCRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion) to, for example, prevent GC pauses during playback.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer and the useful tips. Much appreciated!